# How to get facebook video id by preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

My user copy any video URL and paste in my web input form to submit a video. I using php preg_match to get video id from facebook/you-tube/yahoo/vimeo's URL.
 But every thinks work well without facebook. I cannot get any Facebook video id.

Now a day facebook used different type of url for there video, like:

1. https://www.facebook.com/nikololok/videos/t.100000216422619/10153335471682286/?type=2
2. https://www.facebook.com/nikololok/videos/10153335471682286/
3. https://www.facebook.com/videos/10153335471682286/

Please help me get facebook video ID `10153335471682286` from any of those type url.

my work: (

```
$y_video = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1rethmzohw";
$f_video = "https://www.facebook.com/nikololok/videos/t.100000216422619/10153335471682286/?type=2";
$v_video = "https://vimeo.com/groups/imotional/videos/131543976";

//For facebook
if ($f_video > ''){
    if (preg_match("/(?:.*)\/([0-9]*)/i", $f_video, $matches)) {
    print 'facebook: ' . $matches[1] . '<br />';
    }
}
//For youtube
if ($y_video > ''){
    if (preg_match("/(?:.*)v=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/i", $y_video, $matches)) {
    print 'youtube: ' . $matches[1] . '<br />';
    }
}
//For vimeo
if ($v_video > ''){
    if (preg_match("/(?:.*)\/([0-9]*)/i", $v_video, $matches)) {
    print 'vimeo: ' . $matches[1] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this strange condition `($f_video > '')`?

Comment: Are those the only cases your URLs can be in? If so I think `preg_match("~.*?/videos/(?:t.\d+/(\d+)|(\d+))~i", $f_video, $matches);` should do it. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dB0yX4/1

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte  $f_video = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['f_video']);

Comment: @chris85  Its work well for 1st type of URL but not work for 2nd type of URL above

Comment: The values are in the second grouping, no? Check the regex101, no good?

Comment: You can have the same group if you make the `t\.\d+` part optional: `/videos/(?>t\.\d+/)?(\d+)`

Comment: ^Ah yup was just trying that route out on 101, I came similar to @CasimiretHippolyte's `/videos/(?:t\.\d+)?(\d+)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my answer:

```
<?php
$videos = array('https://www.facebook.com/nikololok/videos/t.100000216422619/10153335471682286/?type=2', 'https://www.facebook.com/nikololok/videos/10153335471682286/', 'https://www.facebook.com/videos/10153335471682286/);');
foreach($videos as $f_video){
    preg_match("~/videos/(?:t\.\d+/)?(\d+)~i", $f_video, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

I changed the delimiter to `~` so the `/`'s in the URL don't need to be escaped.

Here's the regex101 link, https://regex101.com/r/qN8hK8/1, which will give you a detailed description of what the regex is doing. If you have questions please post.

Comment: Thank you sir. I am new in preg_match. So I took time to with your solution. Here I forgot to say, If my user post just any one of above type of URL, I just want to get the ID only.

Comment: doesn't work for `https://www.facebook.com/something/videos/vb.100001360760001/1371428966245002/?type=2&video_source=user_video_tab`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $f_video = "https://www.facebook.com/lshokeenfilms/videos/1668437920119681/";
    $y_video = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1rethmzohw";
    $v_video = "https://vimeo.com/groups/imotional/videos/131543976";

    //For facebook
    if ($f_video > ''){
       if (preg_match("~(?:t\.\d+/)?(\d+)~i", $f_video, $matches)) {
       print 'facebook: ' . $matches[1] . '<br />';
       }
    }
    //For youtube
    if ($y_video > ''){
       if (preg_match("/(?:.*)v=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/i", $y_video, $matches)) {
       print 'youtube: ' . $matches[1] . '<br />';
       }
    }
    //For vimeo
    if ($v_video > ''){
       if (preg_match("/(?:.*)\/([0-9]*)/i", $v_video, $matches)) {
       print 'vimeo: ' . $matches[1] . '<br />';
       }
    }

?>
```